# Ionic - Read file from URI

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, uri

Users of my application can select and crop images using [Ionic Native - Crop](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/crop/). After they have cropped their image, I will have the URI of that image such as:

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myApp/cache/1535369478970-cropped.jpg?1535369482232
```

I want to use [Ionic's File API](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/), since it has a method [readAsDataURL(path, file)](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/#readAsDataURL) which will convert the file to a base64 encoded data url, which is what I exactly need.

However, how would I properly separate the `path` and `file` from the URI of the file I have above so that  `readAsDataURL(path, file)` is satisfied?

I also do not know what these numbers behind the `.jpg?1535369482232` mean and I do not know what the name of the file would be or if it has a different directory on **iOS** since the URI above is provided from a test using Android Emulator.

P.S. I have tried calling the method with just the path above and no file name passed as second argument, but got the following error:

```
{"code":13,"message":"input is not a directory"}
```

How can I achieve the result I want for both iOS and Android file paths?

Answer (score 0):

Your path refers 'cacheDirectory' `this.file.cacheDirectory.`

To get the file name.

```
const pathsplit = "file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myApp/cache/1535369478970-cropped.jpg".split('/');
filename = pathsplit[pathsplit.length-1];
```